# Logging of the success and failure status via Windows bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command

I am creating a bat file to create folders automatically as per one of the tasks.I have written a simple for loop to check for the folder names in the text file and then create that folder automatically.

Here  two cases arise:

**Case 1:** Creates a new folder if the folder doesn't exist.

**Case 2:** Logs the error into the log file that the folder already exists in case if the folder is an existing one.(I've used the `>> folder_create_log.log 2>&1` to achieve the purpose)

But however,I wanted to get the log created for the fodler created succesfully too.For that i thought of using the `%errorlevel%` of the windows bat file.

Code bit as below:

```
set param="

for /F "delims=" %%a in (%FILE_NAME%.txt) do (
mkdir %param%S:\blitz2\Data\%%a\Audit%param% >> folder_create_log.log 2>&1
mkdir %param%S:\blitz2\Data\%%a\Working%param% >> folder_create_log.log 2>&1
mkdir %param%L:\ZaiUpload\Blitz\%%a%param% >> folder_create_log.log 2>&1
mkdir %param%L:\ZaiUpload\Blitz\%%a\Archive%param% >> folder_create_log.log 2>&1

echo %errorlevel%
pause
)
```

But as the `>> folder_create_log.log 2>&1` works fine it is treated as a success and the %errorlevel% is shown as `0` instead of `1`

Could anyone please assist me in getting the successful creation logged into the log file ?

Comment: What is the purpose of variable `raram`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`md test && echo successful`
`&&` works as "if previous command was successful, then".
The opposite is `||` , so a complete command could look like:

```
md test && echo successful || echo failed
```

Comment: ,that works on the command-line,Thanks for that.My intention is to log that into a log file for references.I Tried `mkdir ABC && echo Folder_Created || echo folder_Exists >> folder_create_log.log 2>&1`,But that didn't work.

Comment: @user2075017 - The `||` is comparing the command directly on the left to the command on the right, it's checking the echo command. The command should actually be `(mkdir ABC && echo Folder_Created) || echo failed`

Comment: user2075017 `(md test && echo successful || echo failed) >>file.txt`. @SomethingDark: no need for that parantheses. It works fine without them.

Comment: @Stephan  : It worked mate.Thanks alot both for your help